# Can't access localhost from computer running on same network

Tags: windows, server, ip, localhost, sharing

I'm working on two computers on the same network. **Computer A** has an app working on localhost:4444. However, I can't access it from the browser of **Computer B**.

Here is my situation:

- I pinged it's IP and I'm getting successful responses.
- I've tried accessing through the browser: http://192.168.X.X:4444
- I'm currently sharing files across both computers via the same network successfully.

Can anyone please help me make this work?

Comment: So the app on Computer A is supposed to provide HTTP services?

Comment: @zett42 I'm trying to access localhost:4444 from Computer B, is this not possible?

Comment: I think you should give more details (ideally source code example), what the app on computer A is doing. Otherwise we can only do guesswork.

Comment: localhost:4444 on **Computer B** wouldn't work as [`localhost`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) is the hostname for _**this** computer_. You should be using the IP of **Computer A** to be able to access. Make sure you've enabled firewall on **Computer A** for port 4444. Also, need more information about the web server running as well. It could be the web server configuration as well.

Answer (score 0):

Is port 4444 on Computer A accessible from another computer?

Maybe this helps: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345310(v=sql.100).aspx

(I am posting a reply since I cannot comment...)

Comment: I've opened all the ports on the Firewall, and still can't access it. It just times out